# illegal pream-token (D)

Tags: tables

What is the mistake here? Thank you

```
\documentclass[12pt,a0paper]{report}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell,amsmath, graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}{llllllllll}  
\begin{tabular}
Dráha&  Parametr&   Hodnoty&    Krok&   $\chi^2$&   Dráha&  Parametr&   Hodnoty&    Krok&   $\chi^2$\\

\end{tabular}
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

EDIT

```
\documentclass[12pt,a0paper]{report}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell,amsmath, graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}


\begin{document}
\begin{table} 
\begin{tabular}{llllllllll} 
\multicolumn{5}{*}{Složka 1+3}& \multicolumn{5}{*}{Složka 2}    \\
Dráha&  Parametr&   Hodnoty&    Krok&   $\chi^2$&   Dráha&  Parametr&   Hodnoty&    Krok&   $\chi^2$\\


\end{tabular}
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\multicolumn{<num>}{<align>}{<stuff>}`. `<align>` should be `c`enter, `l`eft, `r`ight or `p{<len>}` for a `p`aragraph-style alignment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tabular preamble is at the wrong place. It should be behind tabular, not table:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a0paper]{report}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell,amsmath, graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{llllllllll}
Dráha&  Parametr&   Hodnoty&    Krok&   $\chi^2$&   Dráha&  Parametr&   Hodnoty&    Krok&   $\chi^2$\\

\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you and please what is the problem in the code in edit?

Answer (score 1):

- please one problem per question
- instead `\multicolumn{5}{*}{Složka 2}` you should write for example `\multicolumn{5}{c}{Složka 2}` (`*`is not valid column specifier)